# Expression evaluator for wp7?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-7

i'm new to wp7 programming and i want to use this C# expression evaluator:
http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/algorithms/a-c-expression-evaluator

i want to use the method evaluate() from this class and the site says:

To evaluate an expression, create an instance of the Eval class and call the Execute() method

How do i do this?

Answer (score 2):

```
Eval ev = new Eval();
ev.Execute("myExpression");
```

Comment: When i put this in my program it says:The type or namespace name 'Eval' could not be found.Do i have to declare somehow the clas Eval.cs in my code";i'm sorry if i ask dumb questions but i'm really new in wp7

Comment: I dont know your project settings. But you have to put on top of your class a "using" statement which enables the use of the eval class. You may even have to add a reference in you project settings.